# Can I add cypress screenshot in mocha awesome html report

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

Im able to generate mocha awesome html report everything fine, but I want to add screenshots in html report im taking cypress screenshot but want to add in html report. Is there any way I can add them?

Comment: [liron\_e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602426) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079846) saying "You can use this plugin that attaches screenshots automatically https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mochawesome-reporter"

Answer (score 0):

Consider mochawesome addContext. This will inject about any value into the report. I'm fairly sure that the html report that is generated will display the image given its path. This may require some further reading on addContext.

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

describe('Cypress tests.', function () {
  before(function () {
    // Perform Cypress things.
    // Take screenshots.
  };

  after(function () {
    const title = 'Screenshot of thing.';
    const value = 'path/to/screenshot.png';
    addContext(this, {
      title,
      value,
    };

  it('Foo should equal batz.', function () {
    // Expect some things.
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to add screenshots automatically to any (and only) failed tests:

```
import addContext from 'mochawesome/addContext'
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        addContext({ test }, {title: 'Screenshot', value: `<path/to/screenshots/folder>/${Cypress.spec.name}/${runnable.parent.title.replace(':', '')} -- ${test.title} (failed).png`})
        addContext({ test }, {title: 'Video', value: `<path/to/videos/folder>/${Cypress.spec.name}.mp4`})
    }
});
```

Put it in *support/index.js* as this file is loaded before any test.

Make sure to update the `<path/to/.../folder>` above to wherever you save screenshots/videos. The path is relative to the generated *html* report.